# Make duplicate of same file using batch file in windows

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

I have 35 image in one folder, say its name is imageset. I want to create 10 copies of each file and rename sequentially. I am ready to do that one by one image. Like there is one image named img_01. So when I create 10 copies the name of the images will be like img_01,img_02,img_03 ... ... img_10 . How can I do that? I tried to use this code. But its not working. What am I missing actually?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET count=10

SET filename=img_
SET start=1
SET extension=.jpg


SET source=%filename%%start%%extension%

FOR /L %%i IN (0, 1, %count%) DO (
  SET /a number=start+%%i

  SET destination=%filename%!number!%extension%
  echo !destination!

  REM ECHO %destination%
  COPY %source% %destination%
)

PAUSE
```

Comment: How is it not working? Apart from that the `copy` command is commented out.

Comment: Endoro, that impairs your ability to solve problems? Impressive.

Comment: @Јοеу It really affected my skills considerably. The user does not expect malicious code from me. I expect (virtual) payment here on SO, not in other forums ... I did not make the rules. :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you're explaining it seems like you want to iterate over all the images in the folder and then create ten copies of each one. The following should do that:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=10
for %%F in (*.jpg) do (
  for /l %%i in (1, 1, %count%) do (
    set num=0%%i
    set num=!num:~-2!
    copy "%%F" "%%~nF_!num!%%~xF"
  )
)
```

Comment: But what if I have to do that for the img_02 too ?! I have to number that from img_11 to img_20(as at the previous batch file upto img_10 have been created)

Comment: You will have to explain further what you need to do.

Comment: The use of a simple FOR loop is risky since it does not buffer the entire directory listing before performing any iterations. It has the potential to create say IMG_10.jpg as one of the 10 copies of IMG_01.jpg, and then go and make ten copies of IMG_10.jpg, etc. Either the loop should be replaced with FOR /F using DIR /B, or else the copies should be placed in a different folder than the source.